# In robots.txt only allow crawling for subdomain NOT subdirectory on shared hosting?

Tags: seo, robots.txt, web-crawler, xml-sitemap

I just changed the DNS settings so the folder `/forum` is now a subdomain instead of a subdirectory.  If I do a robots.txt file and say:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /forum
```

Will that disallow crawling for the subdirectory AND subdomain?

I want to disallow crawling of the subdirectory, but ALLOW crawling of the subdomain.  **Note:** this is on shared hosting so both the subdirectory and subdomain can be visited.  This is why I have this issue.

So, ***How can I only permit crawling for the subdomain?***

Answer (score 0):

It's the correct way, if you want to stop crawling. But note: If the URLs are already indexed, the won't be removed.

The way I would prefer is to set all pages to "noindex/follow" via meta tags or even better you the "canonical tag" to send the search engines traffic to the subdomain url
**Into your**

On a given URL like "http://www.yourdomain.com/directoryname/post-of-the-day" use

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://directoyname.yourdomain.com/post-of-the-day" />
```

The latest URL will be the only one in SERPs